# MySQL: Sum () and Count in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for help using sum() and count () in my SQL query:

```
select s1_s2,count(s1_s2) as RES 
from city_user 
where s1_s2 in (select s1_s2 from city_user ) 
group by s1_s2
```

result: [Image Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DERnL.png)

I want to make  sum () for RES column

Is that possible?

Comment: How exactly do you think text entries "01-02" can be summed?

Comment: @Sumurai8, OP says *I want to make sum () for RES column*

Comment: That makes little sense to me. Unless OP just wants to count how many rows are in the database. Which is just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city_user;`.

Comment: I think you are trying to get the number of paths between two points A and B like paths between two nodes in the graph.. Am I right? Else can you please elaborate a little bit on this like what you would like to achieve with the query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answers

this what I wanted:

look this pic : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuGYs.png)

this query works fine for me:

```
select s1_s2,
count(s1_s2) as res,
(select sum(res) as sum from (
  select s1_s2, count(s1_s2) as res from city_user group by s1_s2) city_user) as Sum_RES from city_user  group by s1_s2
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the **count** of individual s1_s2 values the following query may help

```
select s1_s2, count(s1_s2) as res 
from city_user 
group by s1_s2;
```

To obtain the **sum** of res column the following query may help

```
select sum(res) as sum 
from 
    (select s1_s2, count(s1_s2) as res 
     from city_user 
     group by s1_s1) 
city_user;
```

which is the same as

```
select count(s1_s2) as count 
from city_user;
```

**Reason**: It's because you are trying to group the column based on s1_s2 and obtain its count and store it as `Res` column and calculate its sum which is same as the number of rows for s1_s2 in the table.

Comment: `select distinct(s1_s2)` will not prevent selection of null, which OP's nested query seemed to want to accomplish. `select distinct(s1_s2)` with `group by s1_s2` will obviously not make a difference, because if two values for `s1_s2` are the same, they should be grouped...

Comment: Yeah !! You are right @Sumurai8. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use a outer query like below, again your `WHERE` condition makes no sense as your `IN` clause takes all values of column `s1_s2` from same table which will always be true

```
select *, SUM(RES) as SUM_RES
FROM (
select s1_s2,
count(s1_s2) as RES 
from city_user 
group by s1_s2) xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query makes little sense. `where s1_s2 in (select s1_s2 from city_user )` is just a complicated and REALLY inefficient way of writing `where s1_s2 is not null`.

The sum of the `RES` column is basically the count of all rows in `city_user`, or at least those rows in `city_user` for which `s1_s2` is not null. For the sake of people that need to read your queries in the future, including yourself, make it two queries:

```
select s1_s2,count(s1_s2) as RES 
from city_user 
where s1_s2 is not null
group by s1_s2
```

and

```
select count(*)
from city_user
where s1_s2 is not null
```